# Aspect not invoken before annotation with arguments

Tags: java, aspectj

I have problem with AspectJ. I added arguments to annotation before which Aspect will be woven and as a result it doesn't work.

Annotation interface:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Logged {
   Event event();
   System system();
}
```

My Aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Aspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Logged) && args(event, system)")
    public void invoke(Event event, System system) { }

    @Around("invoke(event, system)")
    public void aspectMethod (ProceedingJoinPoint, Event event, System system) {
        System.out.println(event + " " + system);
    }
}
```

Event and System are Enums.

and added annotation before some method like that:

```
@Logged(event = Event.USER_LOGGED, system = System.WIN)
someTestingMethod();
```

It works only when I leave Aspect as:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class Aspect {
    @Pointcut("@annotation(Logged)")
    public void invoke() { }

    @Around("invoke()")
    public void aspectMethod (ProceedingJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass arguments into Aspect with annotation.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pointcut expressions, but doesn't `args` refer to the arguments to the method call instead of the annotation parameters?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617374/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-spring-aop-advice-with-annotated-parameters

Comment: This solution isn't really what I've been looking for. My annotation must be like:
       @Logged(event = Event.USER_LOGGED, system = System.WIN).
                      I am writing a module to something bigger and my aspect will be invoked before some methods from different modules.

Comment: So most likely you'll need to grab the handle to the `Method` and inspect it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I am working on it. But thank You all for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution is to bind the annotation:

```
@Aspect
class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(l)")
    public void invoke(Logged l) {}

    @Around("invoke(l)")
    public void aspectMethod (ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Logged l) {
        java.lang.System.out.println(l.event()+" "+l.system());
    }
}
```

I've used the execution() pointcut to select only methods (so we want annotated methods) otherwise it will bind other users of the annotation (on fields/types/etc). As someone pointed out, args is for binding method parameters, rather than annotations.