# '@annotation' pointcut does not match ElementType.Parameter annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I want to run an aspect using `ElementType.PARAMETER` annotation but it does not work. The `@Around tokenize` method is never called.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface Tokenize {}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class TokenizeAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(Tokenize)")
    public Object tokenize(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object parameter = joinPoint.getArgs()[0];
        return joinPoint.proceed();
     }
}
```

```java
public void addClientBankAccount(@Tokenize ClientBankAccountRequestCollection) {}
```

Comment: Feedback, please. I don't find it particularly polite to first create a new account here for asking this question and then not reacting to answers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Spring manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators) explains:

> `@annotation`: Limits matching to join points where the subject of the join point (the method being run in Spring AOP) has the given annotation.

You are not targetting an annotated method but an annotated parameter. That must be done differently (be careful with the parentheses):

```java
execution(* *(.., @org.acme.Tokenize (*), ..))
```

This will match any method with any argument annotated by `@Tokenize`. If additionally, you also need to fetch the actual annotation from the method argument and evaluate annotation parameters, check out my related answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/16624766/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50540489/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10595712/1082681